# Terminal wants to install dpkg

Tags: fedora, zsh, dpkg

When I open the terminal a line `Install package 'dpkg' to provide command 'dpkg'? [N/y]` appears. Is there a way to track which program is trying to run this command? I am clueless why this appears in terminal. I am using Fedora 30 and zsh.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but is `dpkg` actually in the Fedora repos? And if so, why?

Comment: It's probably something from your zsh configuration files, e.g. `~/.zshrc`. What's in them? Did you copy them from a machine running a distribution that uses dpkg (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, …)?

Comment: Fedora has `YUM` package management, `dpkg` is `rpm` command in Fedora, You don't need dpkg in Fedora....

Comment: I know that `dpkg` is not meant for fedora, thats why i mentioned it. I just don't know what is causing the need to install the packages. The zshrc config was just fine until today.

Comment: Ok. It was `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. But I do not know why. Any chance of detecting why is it acting this way or should I just reinstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/8253) solved my issue. Thanks all of you! The code solving the problem was made into pull request so all I needed to do at the end was to update oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok. It was source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh. But I do not know why. Any chance of detecting why is it acting this way or should I just reinstall it?

It sounds like you downloaded a script meant to run on a Debian-based distribution. That script expects to call the command `dpkg`. Fedora actually includes a build of dpkg so that you can manipulate Debian packages in a Fedora OS — but it's not not meant to install packages.

However, we also have a tool that helpfully suggests packages to install when you run a command that can't be found. That's what's happening here.

Bottom line: this isn't surprising, but: you'll need a version of your `oh-my-zsh.sh` command meant for Fedora — or else just to replicate whatever that's meant to do yourself.